# What causes a MacBook Pro to randomly have a bad Internet connection for all apps except Safari?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, google-chrome, internet

I had a new **MacBook Pro 16 inch** brought to me from the States to Brazil recently. As time has gone by, the Internet connection on various apps such as WhatsApp, Google Chrome, Adobe Creative Cloud and even the Apple Store have such little bandwidth that they either cannot load anything, or they take so long that they give up. I have a **15 Mbps Internet connection**, and all other devices seem to be connecting just fine (A 2012 MacBook, Windows computers, Android phones, etc.). In fact, when the Macbook Pro 16" connects, it is lightning fast.

To be clear, I do not lose the Internet access completely. **Safari continues to load pages without any issues**

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.4. I have tried:

1. Reboots.
2. Resetting the router.
3. Reinstalling apps, disabling apps, etc.
4. Renewing DHCP lease.
5. Putting `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in the DNS servers list.
6. Searching the Internet for a similar issue with a solution.
7. Turning off all other devices.
8. Removing the dongle and devices.
9. Placing the dongle and USB-C power cables on the opposite side.
10. Removing the Wi-Fi network, and then setting it all up again in System Preferences → Network.
11. Removing all extensions from Google Chrome.

The problem randomly comes and goes, but usually fixes itself when I am not using the computer. I have feared it might be a hardware issue, but since it randomly goes back to working—and working well, I know the hardware still functions. I thought it might be an issue that my ISP can resolve, and have since sent them a message, but have not gotten a response yet.

**Three Other Observations:**

1. Often when Google Chrome has these issues, it is still capable of loading Google-specific sites, such as Google search, YouTube, Google Drive, etc.. I have to revert to Safari to load any webpages outside the Google ecosystem.
2. Opening up a game (World of Tanks) it will tell me that it is downloading the current update, but will remain around 1kb/sec or drop to zero/sec.
3. The computer does not randomly get hot or anything like that.
4. This is a home machine, so there are no company firewalls, etc.
5. There are no programs installed to monitor internet activity, such as antivirus, etc.

**Does anyone know what may be causing this random failure to receive data in all the apps except for Safari or Google's sites in Google Chrome?**

Comment: I have double-checked the firewall settings, and the firewall is turned off.